# Adding bcc malfunctioning - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer

I just came across a problem, spent hours but couldn't found root cause.

Mail sending works fine if I don't add `bcc` option but when I add bcc,

```
 def test_email
   mail :to => 'recipient@xyz.com',
   :subject => 'Sample test',
   :bcc => ['bcc@xyz.com']
 end
```

It sends email to `none` and adds `recipient@xyz.com` as `bcc`.

Here is console output,

```
Mailer.test_email.deliver
#<Mail::Message:63045380, Multipart: true, Headers: <Date: Mon, 02 Jun 2014 13:03:02 +0000>, <From: hostmail@sample.dk>, <To: >, <Cc: >, <Bcc: ["recipient@xyz.com"]>, <Message-ID: <538c760686568_45b9a1001872969@DANVA-test-NAGIOS-monitor.mail>>, <Subject: Sample test>, <Mime-Version: 1.0>, <Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="--==_mimepart_538c76063914_45b9a1001872662"; charset=UTF-8>, <Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit>, <X-Auto-Response-Suppress: OOF>, <Auto-Submitted: auto-generated>>
```

I am using `Rails 3.2.8` and `ruby 1.9.3p545`.

I ideas to fix this prblem?

Comment: what you got inside *logger* ?

Comment: I am not seeing anything wrong.. can you pass those inside the brackets `(..)`.. Wild debug tips although.. :)

Comment: Yes, I tried brackets but not worked :(

Comment: I knew it wouldn't work.. show the content of the [config/environments/$RAILS_ENV.rb](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#example-action-mailer-configuration)..

Comment: Well, It's redmine application. I can't see these setting anywhere.